How to trigger a task during IDEA sync?
I want to execute some task right after user opens my project in IDEA or press the "sync" button:

It seems that there's no reliable way to do it since there's no tasks triggered by IDEA. I find it out this way:
// build.gradle
// I have nothing in this file except things below
tasks.create("asd") {
    doLast {
        println("ASD")
    }
    doFirst {
        println("ASD")
    }
}
tasks.all { Task task ->
    task.dependsOn(tasks.named("asd").get())
}

After I pressed the "sync" button I have no output except this:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 118ms

The best workaround I found - check system properties and modify Gradle start parameters to trigger my tasks if there's a property added by IDEA:
class LocalPropertiesPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(@NotNull Project target) {
        Idea.scheduleTaskAfterIDEASync(target, "mytask");
    }

    private static void scheduleTaskAfterIDEASync(Project target, String taskName) {
        if (isIdeaSync()) modifyGradleStartParameters(target, taskName);
    }

    private static void modifyGradleStartParameters(Project target, String taskName) {
        final StartParameter startParameter = target.getGradle().getStartParameter();
        System.out.println(startParameter);
        final List<TaskExecutionRequest> taskRequests = new ArrayList<>(startParameter.getTaskRequests());
        taskRequests.add(new DefaultTaskExecutionRequest(List.of(taskName)));
        startParameter.setTaskRequests(taskRequests);
    }

    private static boolean isIdeaSync() {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("idea.sync.active", "false"));
    }
}

This doesn't look like good and reliable solution. How to do it in proper way?

If you right-click on a task in the Gradle tool window in IDEA, you can set it to run before or after project sync. See IDEA documentation.

Is it possible to setup this within the build script?

Probably if you dug into the IDEA Gradle plugin
